# System UI won't load at all. (Huawei Vision 2)

Tags: system-error, system-freeze, huawei

So I was on an application and my phone ended up freezing, so I took the battery out to restart it since it was not responding at all. When it restarted however, the system wasn't loading, the screen was black and the only thing onscreen was the little status bar that had the time, signal and battery. I tried holding the far right button on the bottom, and the only thing popping up was the "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped."
Is there a way to fix this at all? I just got this phone about a month ago. I never downloaded any modifications or iffy files onto it either.

Comment: Could be some cache corruption caused by the malbehaving app. Try [booting into recovery-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info) and select "wipe cache", and see if that helps (no data loss unless you hit the "wipe data/factory-reset" instead ;)

Answer (score -3):

System UI is crashed/corrupted due to some problem
Just reinstall android version using PC and it'll be ok

Comment: Could you expand this answer by explaining how to reinstall Android using PC?